# How turn on/off screen pinning programmatically?

Tags: android, security, screen, android-screen-pinning

I want instead of user go to setting>security>screen pinning, user click on button in my app or in tile service to turn screen pinning on/off.

How do i do?

Comment: Its highly unlikely you could without rooting.  The setting is under security.  Its not likely that Android doesn't have it as a protected setting.

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code which you fire on button click

```
setKioskPolicies(false, isAdmin)
            val intent = Intent(applicationContext, MainActivity::class.java).apply {
                addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
            }
            intent.putExtra(LOCK_ACTIVITY_KEY, false)
            startActivity(intent);
```